# UBUNTU server installation roolback

Tags: server, system-installation, 22.04, disk-usage

I have `ubuntu-20.04.1-legacy-server-amd64.iso`(jummy) so had upgraded to 22.04 on VMware workstation VM.

Encountered disk size problem, so turned off the guest, delete snapshots and expand disk 60GB larger.

For extending `/sda/sda5` partition (almost full) read a Q/A.

Advised using `GParted tool` in ISO installation.

**So boot the guest in `ubuntu-20.04.1-legacy-server-amd64.iso` suddenly get partitioning and installing UBUNTU with no prompt!**

My OS was timed more, many configurations, webserver and ... with no backup and snapshots!

**How can I retrieve my UBUNTU server?**

Comment: Apologies, but the situation and the question are unclear. Is the goal to restore the VM to what it was before? Or do you want to recover the data from the VM image?

Comment: Restore the VM to what is was before. The installation ISO suddenly Installed Ubuntu with no prompt and no `GParted tool` ;-( , The disk size get extended, but everything missed. The new `/dev/sda5` partition have 3.9 GB used! Everything jumped ;-( Only the username and password are saved! HELP ME;-( I need restore everything. I had DB, Webserver and etc...

Comment: The Ubuntu server installation is very dangerous. Immediately repartitioning and install OS, without warning, prompt, alert ands there is no options:-(

Comment: The server installation does very little without warning, prompts, or alerts. It expects you are reading the text on the screen. The GParted tool is part of the Ubuntu *Desktop* installation, not server 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Ubuntu Server 22.04 was just a VM and a server at that, and attempting to restore it with recovery tools will not bring it back to what it was. You also deleted all the snapshots. Your best bet would be to reinstall Ubuntu Server 22.04, and next time save a backup of the entire virtual machine disk image before expanding the virtual disk with GParted. It won't take long to reinstall your Ubuntu Server 22.04 guest OS.